# Any ideas why is my Vue.js app working in a codepen but not locally on a jekyll site?

Tags: javascript, jekyll, vue.js

I created a pricing calculator using Vue.js with codepen and recreated here.
it seems to be working fine but when I add it to my jekyll site and run it locally, no vue data is displayed.  I am receiving no errors and tried using the vue dev tools and the data seems to be displaying there.  I also tried wrapping the js code locally with

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  //code in here
  });
```

Is there something I am blatantly missing?  This is my first time working with Vues.js.  Thanks in advance

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // starting values
    analysisDeployment: 0,
    remoteOfficesPhysical: 0,
    remoteOfficesVirtual: 0,
    largeOffices: 0,
    dataCenters: 0,
    additionalApps: 0,
    totalLocations: 0,
    totalApps: 0
  },
  computed: {
    totalMonth: function() {
      var remoteOfficesPhysicalAmount = parseInt(this.remoteOfficesPhysical * 292);
      var remoteOfficesVirtualAmount = parseInt(this.remoteOfficesVirtual * 292);
      var largeOfficesAmount = parseInt(this.largeOffices * 742);
      var dataCentersAmount = parseInt(this.dataCenters * 2150);
      var additionalAppsAmount = parseInt(this.additionalApps * 29);
      var totalApps = parseInt(additionalAppsAmount * this.totalLocations);
      var totalByMonth = parseInt(remoteOfficesPhysicalAmount + remoteOfficesVirtualAmount + largeOfficesAmount + dataCentersAmount + totalApps);
      return totalByMonth;
    },
    totalYear: function() {
      var totalByYear = parseInt(this.totalMonth * 12);
      return totalByYear;
    },
    totalLocations: function() {
      var totalOfficePhyscial = parseInt(this.remoteOfficesPhysical);
      var totalOfficeVirtual = parseInt(this.remoteOfficesVirtual);
      var totalLargeOffice = parseInt(this.largeOffices);
      var totalDataCenter = parseInt(this.dataCenters);
      var grandTotalLocations = parseInt(totalOfficePhyscial + totalOfficeVirtual + totalLargeOffice + totalDataCenter);
      return grandTotalLocations;
    },
    totalHardware: function() {
      var remoteOfficesPhysicalAmount = parseInt(this.remoteOfficesPhysical * 299);
      var remoteOfficesVirtualAmount = parseInt(this.remoteOfficesVirtual * 99);
      var largeOfficesAmount = parseInt(this.largeOffices * 599);
      var dataCentersAmount = parseInt(this.dataCenters * 2199);
      var totalHardwarePoints = parseInt(remoteOfficesPhysicalAmount + remoteOfficesVirtualAmount + largeOfficesAmount + dataCentersAmount);
      return totalHardwarePoints;
    },
    grandTotalCosts: function () {
      var totalCostYear =  parseInt(this.totalYear);
      var totalDeployment = parseInt(this.analysisDeployment);
      var grandTotal = parseInt(totalCostYear + totalDeployment);
      return grandTotal;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #333, 0 0 0px #404040;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0px solid #333;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111, 0 0 0px #1e1e1e;
  border: 3px solid #2691a4;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #2ba3b9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -12.5px;
}
[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #cccccc;
}
[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #333, 0 0 0px #404040;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0px solid #333;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111, 0 0 0px #1e1e1e;
  border: 3px solid #2691a4;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #2ba3b9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 15px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #333, 0 0 0px #404040;
  background: #cccccc;
  border: 0px solid #333;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #333, 0 0 0px #404040;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0px solid #333;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111, 0 0 0px #1e1e1e;
  border: 3px solid #2691a4;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #2ba3b9;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0;
}
[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ccc;
}
[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.7/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container">
   Remote Offices (physical): <input type="range" min="0" step="1" max="100" v-model="remoteOfficesPhysical"> {{ remoteOfficesPhysical }}<br><br>

   Remote Offices (virtual): <input type="range" min="0" step="1" max="100" v-model="remoteOfficesVirtual"> {{remoteOfficesVirtual}}<br><br>

     Large Offices: <input type="range" min="0" step="1" max="100" v-model="largeOffices"> {{largeOffices}}<br><br>

       Data Centers: <input type="range" min="0" step="1" max="100" v-model="dataCenters"> {{dataCenters}}<br><br>
  
  
       Additional Apps: <input type="range" min="0" step="1" max="100" v-model="additionalApps"> {{additionalApps}}<br><br>

  Analysis deployment:
  <select name="analysis" v-model="analysisDeployment">
  <option value="0">Public</option>
  <option value="0">Shared / Public</option>
  <option value="24000">Dedicated / Private</option>
  <option value="39000">Virtual / Private</option>
  <option value="41000">Private, virtual + hardware</option>
</select>
  <span> + ${{ analysisDeployment }}</span>
  
  <h3 class="ui header">Total locations: {{ totalLocations }}</h3>
   <h3 class="ui header">Total monitoring service cost per month: ${{ totalMonth }}</h3>
  <h3 class="ui header">Total monitoring service cost per year: ${{ totalYear }}</h3>
   <h3 class="ui header">Monitoring points hardware costs (one-time cost): ${{ totalHardware}}</h3>
  
    <h3 class="ui header">Grand Total: ${{ grandTotalCosts }}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any issues with your code. Can you please add some details to your jekyll setup? Maybe load order can affect your local app. Have you tested to load Vue.js in header and your script in body? How do you serve your app? For easy starting I would check [Vue-Cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) because there you're up and running quickly. Just run `vue init simple my-project` for simple apps and serve it with [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) or something similar.

Comment: I figured out my problem if anyone else comes I across  this.  I ended up using {% raw %} {% endraw %} around my vue app to keep jekyll from interpreting the double brackets.